# Play Framework 2.0 template engine define writabel variables

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using the play framework template engine based on scala.
The controller are written in Java.

Is there a way to define a inline writable variable?

I just found this at the documentation:

```
@defining(user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName()) {
    <div>Hello @fullName</div>
}
```

But this only create a readonly variable.

Edit:
I am using a loop in my html page:

```
@for(variable <- variables) {
```

This kind of a loop dosen't give me a index variable.
I need this index to give different outputs for the first loop and all others.
Hope this is clear?

So I just thought I could create a index variable outside the loop and increment it on each loop.

Has anyone an idea?
Thanks

Comment: Please write little bit more what do you want to achieve, maybe I can suggest you some other solution, but I need to know more. In general IMHO working with variables on template engine level isn't good idea. On the other hand Play delivers some good helpers (PS also write if you're using a Java or Scala version for your controllers)

Comment: I just edit my post. Hope now its clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
@for(for(i <- 0 to list.size-1) {
   @list(i)
}
```

or simply:

```
@for(i <- list.indices) {
    @list(i)
}
```

([tip from google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/od_gSVGtJdI))

Answer (score 4):

I think zipWithIndex is what you need:

```
@variables.zipWithIndex.map { case (variable,index) => <h1>@variable</h1>}
```